# which version on older laptop?

Tags: performance

my 5 yo acer laptop came with windows vista which was just ok.
I loaded win7 and it is now extremely sluggish.
I'm going to wipe it completely and install an older ubuntu version*
I need it for surfing and video streaming only so I don't need a fully packed version.
Which older ubuntu should I download and use?
intel 585 @ 2.16GHz processor.
1.00 RAM

Answer (score 0):

1 GB of Ram?
I suggest [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) and [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/). Further, I also suggest using the LTS version. If you do not understand, refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Wiki- [Lubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubuntu) and [Xubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu)